# What happened to Vigilante?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In season 5 of *Arrow*, we are introduced to a character known as "Vigilante". He generally seems to be a good guy, attacking gangs, but also clashes with Team Arrow on occasion.

[image: AKA: Mr Ski Goggles]

As the main plot with Prometheus unfolds, Vigilante disappears from the show, and is not referenced again.

Is there any explanation in or out-of-universe explaining the disappearance of Vigilante?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It looks like the character was put on ice until next season](http://hiddenremote.com/2017/04/20/arrow-season-5-will-vigilantes-identity-revealed/):

> With Season 5 quickly coming to a close, one would assume that **the big
>   reveal of Vigilante’s identity** is right around the corner. However,
>   **the writers have chosen to take their time in playing out the mystery
>   by going with a slow-burning reveal that will span multiple seasons.**
>
> “We talked a lot about it in the writers’ room. We know who it is. We
>   know who’s underneath the mask. And we got excited about the
>   possibility of playing out that mystery a little longer,” Arrow
>   executive producer Marc Guggenheim revealed in a recent statement to
>   TV Guide. “Apart from the flashbacks, we really haven’t had a mystery
>   that stretched over seasons. So we’re like, you know what? We’ve got a
>   lot going on in Season 5. We’re going to save this for Season 6.”

Comment: Wrong linky link? :D

Comment: Link works for me.

Comment: @BCdotWEB i fixed the link to what it appeared was your source. original was borked.